# Task scheduling with Redis

Tags: java, spring, redis

I need to build a program that receives payment ID and sends a request after 30 seconds to another web service to check if payment is successful. 
Program will receive 500-1000 transactions per minute so I think it is not efficient to use Java Thread Pool for this task.

I am thinking to use Redis to keep payment IDs that need to be checked.
And IDs should be called one by one according to issued time (each ID must be called after 30 seconds).

As I know so far, I can use SET key-value data type:

`SET ID TIMESTAMP`

Is this the correct way to implement the program? Any other options do you recommend?

I am using Spring Boot and PostgreSql for database.

Comment: Do you need to run a payment check request at the exact time of receiving_time+30 sec or do you just need to run it any time after 30 sec. ? I am not expecting the former as the requirement but who knows?  Nevertheless your issue will not be Java Thread Pool at all as it can easily support such a small load. The real ugly part will be payment check request waiting time and if necessary state update for payment id. What is the requirement for the handling of response from payment check service and fail cases? What is the expected execution time for a check call?

Comment: @cool Payment check request need to be run any time after 30 sec. Request waiting time is 10 secs, and yes it updates payment state after receiving response. In case fail, status will be remained pending.

Answer (score 1):

The use case seems to be delayed message processing.Here Active MQ/or RabbitMQ message processing can be use which support delayed message processing.
[RabbitMQ](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/delayed-messages.html).If it is not scalable for your use case then you can store your message in some  NOSQL DB (Cassandra) by shard way with fixed bucket size say the event is scheduled for 10:21:55 AM, then the bucket is 10:21:00 AM).And a master process pick the eligible bucket and distributed among worker for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis zset (Sorted Set), which stores the elements in order bases on given score, for more you can check how sorted set works.

Example:

```
zadd SET_NAME PAYMENT_ID ISSUED_TIME(EPOCH)
```

Then run a scheduler after every around 10 secs, that will fetch payment ids from sorted set bases on score like:

```
zrangebyscore SET_NAME LONG.MIN_VALUE CURRENT_TIME
```

I hope this will help in your case